# Приведение неправильных значений к дефолтному при парсинге значений библиотекой argparse

Tags: python, парсер, argparse

У меня есть параметр, который должен принимать значения от 1 до 100 включительно, если он задан. Если он не задан или пользователь ввёл некорректное значение(например 109 или - 12), то значение должно приводиться к дефолтному. Собственно суть вопроса: как этого добиться?

Привожу полный код:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--barbie", type=int, nargs='?', choices=range(0, 100), default=50)
parser.add_argument("--cars", type=int, nargs='?', choices=range(0, 100), default=50)
parser.add_argument("--movie", type=str, nargs='?', choices=['melodrama', 'football', 'other'], default='other')
args = parser.parse_args()
ch = ['melodrama', 'other', 'football']
print(f'boy: {int((100 - args.barbie + args.cars + (ch.index(args.movie) * 50)) / 3)}')
print(f'girl: {int(100 - (100 - args.barbie + args.cars + (ch.index(args.movie) * 50)) / 3)}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Идеологическое отступление (ответ ниже)

- Можно догадаться, что это программа для определения *гендера* на основе личного рейтинга кукол, машинок и предпочитаемых жанров кино. Почему, если пользователь не задал рейтинг для машинок, то это значение 50%? Может, лучше [попросить его определится](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#required), мотивируя это повышением точности итоговых результатов?
- Если пользователь ввел что-то некорректное, надо трубить ему об этом. Надо рассказать, что он сделал не так и как может это исправить. Не стоит принимать решения за пользователя. Если пользователю нравятся куклы на 109%, а машинки он ненавидит на 12%, то это ему можно сказать, что методологии тестирования пока не умеют учитывать подобные мнения!:)
- Писать `choices=range(0, 100)` хоть и можно, но это выглядит странно. Этот параметр придуман не для этого. Вы только посмотрите на это:

```
$ python3 main.py -h
usage: main.py [-h]
               [--barbie [{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99}]]
               [--cars [{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99}]]
               [--movie [{melodrama,football,other}]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --barbie [{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99}]
  --cars [{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99}]
  --movie [{melodrama,football,other}]
```

Варианты для `movie` - все хорошо, претензий нет. В остальном, согласитесь, получается громоздко.

### Как, все-таки, добиться желаемого

Только навешивать свою проверку и использовать [argparse.ArgumentParser.get_default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.get_default), библиотека не имеет встроенных средств для такой продвинутой валидации и, тем более, автоматического изменения пользовательского ввода:

```
import argparse

ch = ['melodrama', 'other', 'football']

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--barbie", type=int, nargs='?', default=50)
parser.add_argument("--cars", type=int, nargs='?', default=50)
parser.add_argument("--movie", type=str, nargs='?', choices=ch, default='other')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.barbie < 0 or args.barbie > 100:
    args.barbie = parser.get_default('barbie')
if args.cars < 0 or args.cars > 100:
    args.cars = parser.get_default('cars')

print(f'boy: {int((100 - args.barbie + args.cars + (ch.index(args.movie) * 50)) / 3)}')
print(f'girl: {int(100 - (100 - args.barbie + args.cars + (ch.index(args.movie) * 50)) / 3)}')
```

Comment: Дело в том, что это не проект для работы с человеком как таковой, а задача из курса изучения языка. Все значения там вводятся проверяющей системой, так что такая реализация вытекает из самого задания. Спасибо за ответ, я сам хотел сделать подобную проверку, но подумал, что есть более элегантное решение с использованием методов библиотеки. Спасибо за потраченное вами время